# Ukrainian biometric passports

Tags: visas, passports, canada, ukrainian-citizens

With the new biometric passports of the Ukraine coming out next year, will a visitor visa still be required to enter Canada?

Comment: Let us see real biometric passports first - they have been discussed for years, there is no certainty the passports are at all going to be issued as announced. I recently read that visa-free EU visits with a bio passport **might** start being available in fall 2015 only.

Answer (score 4):

There is no way to know *for certain* until it happens and the Canadian government decides to update requirements, however, for an educated guess only:

Since citizens of Lithuania and Poland who have obtained a biometric passport (e-passport) are allowed to visit Canada visa-free, it stands to reason that, eventually, Canada may extend the same courtesy to citizens of Ukraine.

There are many reasons, however, that Canada could decide to keep the Ukraine on the visa-required list. Again, we won't know, until we know; ya know?

Comment: It's worth noting that both Poland and Lithuania are part of the European Union, while Ukraine isn't.

Answer (score 4):

Ukraine is not on the list of [countries and effective dates](http://www.cic.gc.ca/english/visit/biometrics.asp) and [“If you submit your application in person at a visa application centre (VAC) that offers biometric services before the date the requirement takes effect for your country, you will not have to pay the biometric fee and you can get VAC application services at no cost.”](http://www.canadainternational.gc.ca/trinidad_and_tobago-trinite_et_tobago/visas/study-etude.aspx?lang=eng).

This may suggest that visas will still be required since ["You can give your biometrics at the VAC in Kyiv and Lviv”](http://www.canadainternational.gc.ca/ukraine/visas/index.aspx?lang=eng) but it seems visas are at present required nonetheless.

As of early 2017, Canada still [requires a visa](http://www.cic.gc.ca/english/visit/visas.asp) for Ukranian passport holders (usually).